# Whats wrong with these Heroku Logs

Tags: node.js, git, heroku

So this app works fine on my local:3000, and I can get it to work on heroku fine. The problem is I have api keys I dont want tracked. So I removed them from the catch, and then I try and re upload the application and it fails. This would not be a problem if I didn't have to constantly update the application with auto deploys from git hub. But the secound I make and update to my github version, where the .gitignore file untracks my json file with my api keys, the application breaks. Please help Thanks

```
`remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote: 
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:        
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote: 
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:        
remote:        Resolving node version (latest stable) via semver.io...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 5.10.0...
remote:        Using default npm version: 3.8.3
remote: 
remote: -----> Restoring cache
remote:        Skipping cache restore (new runtime signature)
remote: 
remote: -----> Building dependencies
remote:        Pruning any extraneous modules
remote:        Installing node modules (package.json)
remote:        appname@0.0.0 /tmp/build_5014610d3b523f7ab52c0fa545ba8ec1
remote:        ├─┬ body-parser@1.15.0
remote:        │ ├── bytes@2.2.0
remote:        │ ├── content-type@1.0.1
remote:        │ ├─┬ debug@2.2.0
remote:        │ │ └── ms@0.7.1
remote:        │ ├── depd@1.1.0
remote:        │ ├─┬ http-errors@1.4.0
remote:        │ │ ├── inherits@2.0.1
remote:        │ │ └── statuses@1.2.1
remote:        │ ├── iconv-lite@0.4.13
remote:        │ ├─┬ on-finished@2.3.0
remote:        │ │ └── ee-first@1.1.1
remote:        │ ├── qs@6.1.0
remote:        │ ├─┬ raw-body@2.1.6
remote:        │ │ ├── bytes@2.3.0
remote:        │ │ └── unpipe@1.0.0
remote:        │ └─┬ type-is@1.6.12
remote:        │   ├── media-typer@0.3.0
remote:        │   └─┬ mime-types@2.1.10
remote:        │     └── mime-db@1.22.0
remote:        ├── ejs@2.4.1
remote:        ├─┬ express@4.13.4
remote:        │ ├─┬ accepts@1.2.13
remote:        │ │ └── negotiator@0.5.3
remote:        │ ├── array-flatten@1.1.1
remote:        │ ├── content-disposition@0.5.1
remote:        │ ├── cookie@0.1.5
remote:        │ ├── cookie-signature@1.0.6
remote:        │ ├── escape-html@1.0.3
remote:        │ ├── etag@1.7.0
remote:        │ ├── finalhandler@0.4.1
remote:        │ ├── fresh@0.3.0
remote:        │ ├── merge-descriptors@1.0.1
remote:        │ ├── methods@1.1.2
remote:        │ ├── parseurl@1.3.1
remote:        │ ├── path-to-regexp@0.1.7
remote:        │ ├─┬ proxy-addr@1.0.10
remote:        │ │ ├── forwarded@0.1.0
remote:        │ │ └── ipaddr.js@1.0.5
remote:        │ ├── qs@4.0.0
remote:        │ ├── range-parser@1.0.3
remote:        │ ├─┬ send@0.13.1
remote:        │ │ ├── destroy@1.0.4
remote:        │ │ └── http-errors@1.3.1
remote:        │ ├── serve-static@1.10.2
remote:        │ ├── utils-merge@1.0.0
remote:        │ └── vary@1.0.1
remote:        └─┬ sendgrid@1.9.2
remote:        ├── lodash@3.10.1
remote:        ├── mime@1.3.4
remote:        ├─┬ request@2.70.0
remote:        │ ├── aws-sign2@0.6.0
remote:        │ ├─┬ aws4@1.3.2
remote:        │ │ └─┬ lru-cache@4.0.1
remote:        │ │   ├── pseudomap@1.0.2
remote:        │ │   └── yallist@2.0.0
remote:        │ ├─┬ bl@1.1.2
remote:        │ │ └─┬ readable-stream@2.0.6
remote:        │ │   ├── core-util-is@1.0.2
remote:        │ │   ├── isarray@1.0.0
remote:        │ │   ├── process-nextick-args@1.0.6
remote:        │ │   ├── string_decoder@0.10.31
remote:        │ │   └── util-deprecate@1.0.2
remote:        │ ├── caseless@0.11.0
remote:        │ ├─┬ combined-stream@1.0.5
remote:        │ │ └── delayed-stream@1.0.0
remote:        │ ├── extend@3.0.0
remote:        │ ├── forever-agent@0.6.1
remote:        │ ├─┬ form-data@1.0.0-rc4
remote:        │ │ └── async@1.5.2
remote:        │ ├─┬ har-validator@2.0.6
remote:        │ │ ├─┬ chalk@1.1.3
remote:        │ │ │ ├── ansi-styles@2.2.1
remote:        │ │ │ ├── escape-string-regexp@1.0.5
remote:        │ │ │ ├─┬ has-ansi@2.0.0
remote:        │ │ │ │ └── ansi-regex@2.0.0
remote:        │ │ │ ├── strip-ansi@3.0.1
remote:        │ │ │ └── supports-color@2.0.0
remote:        │ │ ├─┬ commander@2.9.0
remote:        │ │ │ └── graceful-readlink@1.0.1
remote:        │ │ ├─┬ is-my-json-valid@2.13.1
remote:        │ │ │ ├── generate-function@2.0.0
remote:        │ │ │ ├─┬ generate-object-property@1.2.0
remote:        │ │ │ │ └── is-property@1.0.2
remote:        │ │ │ ├── jsonpointer@2.0.0
remote:        │ │ │ └── xtend@4.0.1
remote:        │ │ └─┬ pinkie-promise@2.0.0
remote:        │ │   └── pinkie@2.0.4
remote:        │ ├─┬ hawk@3.1.3
remote:        │ │ ├── boom@2.10.1
remote:        │ │ ├── cryptiles@2.0.5
remote:        │ │ ├── hoek@2.16.3
remote:        │ │ └── sntp@1.0.9
remote:        │ ├─┬ http-signature@1.1.1
remote:        │ │ ├── assert-plus@0.2.0
remote:        │ │ ├─┬ jsprim@1.2.2
remote:        │ │ │ ├── extsprintf@1.0.2
remote:        │ │ │ ├── json-schema@0.2.2
remote:        │ │ │ └── verror@1.3.6
remote:        │ │ └─┬ sshpk@1.7.4
remote:        │ │   ├── asn1@0.2.3
remote:        │ │   ├─┬ dashdash@1.13.0
remote:        │ │   │ └── assert-plus@1.0.0
remote:        │ │   ├── ecc-jsbn@0.1.1
remote:        │ │   ├── jodid25519@1.0.2
remote:        │ │   ├── jsbn@0.1.0
remote:        │ │   └── tweetnacl@0.14.3
remote:        │ ├── is-typedarray@1.0.0
remote:        │ ├── isstream@0.1.2
remote:        │ ├── json-stringify-safe@5.0.1
remote:        │ ├── node-uuid@1.4.7
remote:        │ ├── oauth-sign@0.8.1
remote:        │ ├── stringstream@0.0.5
remote:        │ ├── tough-cookie@2.2.2
remote:        │ └── tunnel-agent@0.4.2
remote:        └── smtpapi@1.2.0
remote:        
remote: 
remote: -----> Caching build
remote:        Clearing previous node cache
remote:        Saving 2 cacheDirectories (default):
remote:        - node_modules
remote:        - bower_components (nothing to cache)
remote: 
remote: -----> Build succeeded!
remote:        ├── body-parser@1.15.0
remote:        ├── ejs@2.4.1
remote:        ├── express@4.13.4
remote:        └── sendgrid@1.9.2
remote:        
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> web
remote: 
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 17.2M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v3
remote:        https://safe-brook-78904.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy.... done.`
```

Comment: have you ever seen it work on heroku? the build seems fine, just a quick question before I dig in more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have private information you don't want to store with your repo, you should be supplying those values through environment variables.

Look into using `process.env` in your application, and supplying what Heroku calls [Config Vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#setting-up-config-vars-for-a-deployed-application) on their end.

Comment: Yup that whats I was just about to post!

Comment: Yeah, it *sounds* like the application itself is failing because it's trying to read a `json` file that isn't there anymore. Which is fine -- that file shouldn't be there, if it contains private information. But it's hard to say with the stuff above, since the build itself doesn't fail. Sounds like a runtime issue.

Comment: thanks mate this solved it for me, it was just an issue with how I was tryingn to hide the api keys this was the better way